# Cordova Android build error: ":app:processReleaseGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask')"

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, build

**Current Behavior**

When trying to build my Ionic Cordova app for Android I get the following error:

Build command: `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

```
    Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices FAILED
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').
      - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'intermediateDir' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputDirectory.
        
        Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
        
        Possible solutions:
          1. Add a getter for field 'intermediateDir'.
          2. Remove the annotations on 'intermediateDir'.
        
        Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
      - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR1' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
        
        Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
        
        Possible solutions:
          1. Add a getter for field 'packageNameXOR1'.
          2. Remove the annotations on 'packageNameXOR1'.
        
        Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
      - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR2' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
        
        Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
        
        Possible solutions:
          1. Add a getter for field 'packageNameXOR2'.
          2. Remove the annotations on 'packageNameXOR2'.
        
        Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
      - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'quickstartFile' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @InputFile, @Optional.
        
        Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
        
        Possible solutions:
          1. Add a getter for field 'quickstartFile'.
          2. Remove the annotations on 'quickstartFile'.
        
        Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
      - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'searchedLocation' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
        
        Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
        
        Possible solutions:
          1. Add a getter for field 'searchedLocation'.
          2. Remove the annotations on 'searchedLocation'.
        
        Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
    
    You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
    
    See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    
    BUILD FAILED in 6s
    4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
    Command failed with exit code 1: /Users/derekmiller/Zogo/Zogo-Frontend/platforms/android/gradlew :app:bundleRelease -b /Users/derekmiller/Zogo/Zogo-Frontend/platforms/android/build.gradle
    [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
            
            cordova build android --release exited with exit code 1.
```

This build error started after upgrading from cordova-android `8.1.1` to `10.1.1`.  We were forced to make this change so that we can target Android API 30.

**Expected Behavior**

The app to build successfully

**What have I tried**

- most of the other people that have had this error said that this could be solved by ensuring the google services version was `4.3.8`
- We tried to do this by setting `classpath com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8` directly in the `build.gradle`
- We also tried to do this by adding the following to `config.xml`:

```
   <preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled" value="true" />
   
   <preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion" value="4.3.8" />
```

- The error persisted after both of these changes
- Setting `<preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />` in my `config.xml`

**Technical Details**

- Ionic CLI: 5.4.16
- Cordova CLI: 9.0.0
- Cordova Android: 10.1.1
- Android SDK Tools: 26.1.1
- OS: macOS Big Sur
- project.properties:

```
    target=android-30
    
    android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
    android.library.reference.2=app
    cordova.gradle.include.1=branch-cordova-sdk/child-rules.gradle
    cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0
    cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/child-FCMPlugin.gradle
    cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9
    cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0
    cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-ionic/child-cordovapluginionic.gradle
    cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1
    cordova.system.library.5=androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
    cordova.system.library.6=com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.9.1
    cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.+
    cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.+
    cordova.system.library.9=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by setting a global google services version in the the root `build.gradle`

```
    allprojects {
        // other settings
    
        ext {
            GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION = '4.3.10'
        }
    }
```

The other ways I was trying to set the google services version weren't working because there was some other plugin that was trying to use a different version of google services.  I believe setting the version this way ensures that they are all using the same version.

Comment: Disclaimer: as good as this might have been for the OP, it's not an ideal solution since `build.gradle` is a generated file, and thus, will be erased if the platform gets upgraded or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using phonegap-plugin-push, it will cause this error because it references an outdated version of Google Services. It can be replaced:

```
cordova plugin remove phonegap-plugin-push
cordova plugin add @havesource/cordova-plugin-push
```

Any references to phonegap-plugin-push would need to be updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanna ask have you tried doing it the following way without changing the build file itself, if not, try it and rebuild it, let me know

To upgrade:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@10.1.1
```

Comment: Yes.  That's how I updated to cordova-android 10.1.1 in the first place

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this issue on the abandoned `@havesource` fork](https://github.com/havesource/cordova-plugin-push/issues/113#issuecomment-919869702), a more sustainable solution to override the Google Services version is adding the following to `config.xml` (instead of editing generated files as the OP's answer suggests):

```xml
<platform name="android">
  <!-- ... -->
  <!-- this next tag doesn't seem necessary in my scenario, but it's cited in many places; YMMV -->
  <!-- preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled" value="true" /-->
  <preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion" value="4.3.15" />
</platform>
```

**Note:** many versions were reported to fix the problem, such as 4.3.8 (linked issue), 4.3.10 (OP) and 4.3.15 (me); again, YMMV.